# Apache-Kafka: Issue in creating topic using windows cmd

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I am new to Apache-Kafka.I am using:
    zookeeper-3.6.0
    kafka-2.13-2.4.1
    Windows-7

```
Earlier i was able to create and list topics on the same machine.
After i restarted my system, i am unable to create and list topics.
I am getting below errors.
```

Create error: 
[Topic create error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlDXh.png)
     List error:
[List Topic Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3bVx.png)

The error looks pretty simple. I googled a lot but unfortunately, i am not able to get a solution to this.

I followed the below link for configurations:
       http://programming-tips.in/kafka-set-up-apache-kafka-on-windows/

Looking forward for some expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

Type it out manually and it will work.
There is something wrong with the '-' in the example code.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, it worked out by manually typing the command...Really strange, copy paste should also work...

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. Appreciate it if you could mark the response as the answer since it worked.